# EJBCA SCP Publishing Error, could not connect to CRL destination

Tags: ejbca

Im getting very frustrated with what should be simple so im asking this on SO as well as sourceforge. I am trying to set up a simple scp connection from my CA to my VA. The key and the permissions on the key are fine. I can use it to scp anything from the command line to the directory of choice. But when I try to set up what should be the exact same configuration in the admin GUI I constantly get the error below.

The directory does exist.
It has the correct owner and write permissions.
The ssh key is working.
The users are correct and have the correct permissions.
The known hosts file is correct.

What could possibly be wrong? The server logs dont help at all they just say the same thing the gui does.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check the SSH servers log. It should give you some information, if the network connection gets it there.